# Convert Idea code formatter xml to support STS

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, code-formatting, sts

I have a code formatter XML to support IDEA. Now I need to convert it to support eclipse STS.
How can I do that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to is there a way to convert my intellij code formatted XML to STS code formatter

Comment: Please take a moment to read [ask].